# standalone tool for generating makefile(s) from Eclipse's .cproject file?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Is there a standalone tool, that can be ran from a shell script, to generate a makefile from the .cproject? Actually, the same functionality as the CDT itself, but that can be non-interactive.

As is probably obvious, I want to be able to run a script that checkouts and builds the software, comprising from several C++ project. I am trying to avoid moving to a build system like maven, as it seems as like an overhead in this early stage of our project. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that there was discussions on the CDT-dev mailinglist a few months back about having a command-line tool for building CDT projects. Writing such a tool is really not very difficult (there was an example mentioned), it is simply a matter of defining your own Eclipse-application, load the project, and build it. Searching the CDT-dev list on "standalone build" should give you some relevant hits.

Comment: thanks! (short comments are not allowed here, so this is to make it longer :)